# Dynamically populate Cascading Dropdown from MySQL using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, mysql, front-end, dropdown

What I'd like to achieve is managing tables in the front-end of a WordPress page the same way as MS Access does. So, I'd like to show dependent cascading dropdown which are related by foreign key and then click on some buttons for executing my insert/update query.

I honestly find it very strange that there is nothing out there (not even a premium plugin) for doing such operations since they are really useful and used by nearly every business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [CRED plugin](http://wp-types.com/home/cred/) and see if it gets you anywhere near what you need. I've worked with it back when it was three different plugins (Types, Views and Access).

For as much as I can remember they used to keep a testing environment where you could take plugins for a spin in a clean site on their server before you bought it, you should ask them about that.

Comment: Most likely it's exactly what I was looking for. This toolset seems really to be able to do anything. Anyway, from what I can see, it doesn't seem to be able to manage also custom tables (not related to WordPress). Can you confirm that?

Comment: I haven't tested CRED at all, even though i've been invited to, when it was launched. All I know about it is that it was made for creating and maintaining custom post types and taxonomies back when few were aware that they even existed in WP. It is developed by icanlocalize, the guys behind WPML. I'm not affiliated with them in anyway, but, using their products in the past i can vouch for their solid skills, knowledge of WP and quality of service. Ok, maybe not `vouch`. Let's say `admit`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin comes close to what you want? https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/screenshots/

However, you can use something like Sequel Pro to connect to the database to build SQL queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however that is not what I want to do. I need to build a user-friendly mask to be shown in the front-end for inserting data into the database tables. The plugin which I thought best fit to my purpose is wpDataTables; anyway, I discovered at a later time that it actually isn't able to properly manage a database since it cannot correctly modify a view nor it is "smart" enough to notice if a field is a foreign key and so show a dropdown with the decoded values of the related table as MS Access does.

Comment: Here are some examples of what I'd like to do: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist and http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists-Plugin.html. Unfortunately I'm not that good in JQuery/AJAX, so the only thing I managed to do so far is a dropdown list generated by PHP code from MySQL.